# AppWarp game fails to connect

Tags: java, android, libgdx, appwarp

I am trying to run [this](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/java-multiplayer-libgdx-tutorial/) demo which is a simple libgdx game, implementing the AppWarp multi player API, but it doesn't work. I'm running the desktop version of the game, it starts up fine but it won't connect to AppWarp. It 'tries to connect' for a while, then the connect event comes back with a result '5' which is an underlying TCP connection error as stated [here](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/ios-game-developers-home/ios-client-result/). I'm running it on Windows 7 OS, tried disabling firewall and security essentials all to no avail.
Any idea as to what the problem might be?

Comment: Are you referring to the [tutorial here](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/java-multiplayer-libgdx-tutorial/)? Have you put your application keys?

Comment: Yes that's the tutorial. I entered the api keys, I tried it first with a wrong one and then I got a fileNotFoundException. It does give multiple options when creating an app in the dashboard and it wasn't very clear which I should choose. So first I tried Mobile Cloud API App and that's when I got the fileNotFoundException so then I tried the Multiplayer WARP Cloud App and that key seems to work but I can't get it to connect.

Comment: yes you need to create WARP type of app for connecting to AppWarp cloud servers. Do WarpClient.enableTrace(true); after you initialize. This will print logs to System.Out. Perhaps that will be give a hint as to what is wrong. Also curious what you mean by 'WARP Cloud App and that key seems to work' if you couldn't connect?

Comment: it's giving me 'AppWarpTrace :1393096235660:shouldStop... returning' in the console, so not much wiser. And I assumed the key worked because i didn't got the fileNotFoundException as I did with the other key and the connection result code 5 clearly states that there is a TCP connection error and no key error.

Comment: Is that all that you get? no exception trace etc.? to confirm that its not a machine config issue, can you try telnet to the server.. do "telnet appwarp.shephertz.com 12346"

Comment: connect failed, I can't telnet to that server. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: I can't ping appwarp.shephertz.com either, this is strange I can ping google just fine

Comment: probably you're behind some gateway/firewall that only allows http/port 80 traffic

Comment: also ping won't work to appwarp.shephertz.com - ICMP pings are disabled. see if you can telnet to any other server which is running on a port other than 80/8080/443 - http/https ports